# Tabulator.js Stop initial ajax data load and load data after first filter

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I am using tabulator.js library and would like to start loading data after first filter, not immediately after page load. Something like this:

```
initialAjaxLoad: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do not set the ***ajaxURL*** in your initial constructor which will cause the table to load with no data

You can then call the ***setData*** function whenever you are ready to load the data:

```
table.setData("http://your.url.com"):
```